# How to make a Storyboard image fill its frame entirely?

Tags: swift, xcode, storyboard

Notice how the System image: `Person.crop.circle` does not touch the edges of the frame. How do I fix that?

(Also I don't want to write code for this, please let me know how to fix this in storyboard).

[image: example Image]

[Storyboard screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3s5k.png)

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set **point-Size** within **Configuration** under in the **Attributes Inspector** equal to 1